# Kenward-Roger degrees of freedom with lmerTest

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, degrees-of-freedom

I am trying to do a *t*-test with Kenward-Roger degrees of freedom on my linear mixed model with lmerTest in R. I found that there are two ways of specifying the degrees of freedom: either directly in the lmerTest::lmer call or a posteriori in the summary of the lmerModLmerTest object. Both however yield different standard errors, df's and hence *t*- and *p*-values. What is the difference between the two?

```
> fit <- lmerTest::lmer(Y_st ~ 1 + Phase + Time + Phase:Time + (1 + Phase + Time + Phase:Time | Name), data)
> fit_KR <- lmerTest::lmer(Y_st ~ 1 + Phase + Time + Phase:Time + (1 + Phase + Time + Phase:Time | Name), data, ddf = "Kenward-Roger")

> summary(fit, ddf = "Kenward-Roger")$coefficients
              Estimate Std. Error       df   t value     Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)  6.4783938 0.42753044 3.964739 15.153058 0.0001172072
Phase       -2.6260150 1.04879283 3.971262 -2.503845 0.0669419690
Time         0.4435164 0.05880399 3.672213  7.542284 0.0023120158
Phase:Time  -0.5026759 0.18613694 2.329488 -2.700570 0.0969816179

> summary(fit_KR)$coefficients
              Estimate Std. Error        df   t value     Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)  6.4783938 0.42053719  5.404908 15.405044 1.131924e-05
Phase       -2.6260150 1.03170186  4.070845 -2.545323 6.255708e-02
Time         0.4435164 0.05466193 62.989420  8.113808 2.259034e-11
Phase:Time  -0.5026759 0.13232598 31.521141 -3.798769 6.248813e-04
```

Comment: The first version is wrong, you can't specify `ddf` in the `lmerTest::lmer` call. I get an `extra argument(s) ‘ddf’ disregarded ` warning if I try to do this, perhaps my version of `lmerTest` (3.1-1) has added this warning.